# A schema which allows elements to be in any order but with no duplicates?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to write an XSD schema in which some elements can appear in any order - but there can be no duplicates.

So this is valid:

```
<parent>
    <my-element-A>1</my-element-A>
    <my-element-B>2</my-element-B>
    <my-element-C>3</my-element-C>
</parent>
```

... and this is valid:

```
<parent>
    <my-element-B>2</my-element-B>
    <my-element-A>1</my-element-A>
    <my-element-C>3</my-element-C>
</parent>
```

But this is not:

```
<parent>
    <my-element-A>1</my-element-A>
    <my-element-B>2</my-element-B>
    <my-element-A>1</my-element-A><!-- Fail! Duplicate my-element-A -->
    <my-element-C>3</my-element-C>
</parent>
```

How can I do this with XSD?

Comment: Is the uniqueness constraint on the element name or on the element content?  Does your example fail because there are two `my-element-A` elements? Or because there are two elements whose value is 1?  In the former case, accept the answer from Richard JP Le Guen; in the latter, read up on `xs:unique`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<xs:all>` element defines ["A grouping of a sequence is a set of sub-sequences, some or all of which may be empty, such that each member of the original sequence appears once and only once in one of the sub-sequences and all members of all sub-sequences are in the original sequence."](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#all-mg)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="parent">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all minOccurs="0">
          <xs:element name="my-element-A" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="my-element-B" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="my-element-C" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:all>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```